# Full Screen Window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing an application in c# using WPF. I am using

```
Height="768" Width="1366" Loaded="WindowLoaded" 
WindowStyle="ToolWindow" WindowState="Maximized"
```

parameters. Now to create full screen I change the WindowStyle to None. This does make it full screen but the close button disappears. Also the full screen doesn't cover the taskbar. Any suggestions?

Comment: So you want a full screen window but still have a window default close button :|?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With WPF you almost never must define `Width` and `Height` properties. WPF will render your screens much better by using relative sizes. So if you want a full screen `ToolWindow` which covers the taskbar use:

```
WindowStyle="ToolWindow" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowState="Maximized"
```

in your xaml.